# O que são e onde estão a "stack" e "heap"?

Tags: memória, gerenciamento-de-memória, stack, heap

O que são esses tais de *stack* e *heap* que tanto se fala em gerenciamento de memória?

Isso realmente são porções da memória como algumas pessoas falam ou é apenas um conceito abstrato para facilitar o entendimento da forma como se gerencia a memória?

Algum deles é mais rápido que o outro? Se um é claramente mais rápido, por que existe o outro?

Faz diferença se estou usando, por exemplo, Assembly, C, Java, ou Javascript, Windows ou Linux? Isso é controlado pela "linguagem" ou pelo sistema operacional?

Enfim, queria entender melhor esse conceito que parece ser mal compreendido pelos programadores. Seria muito útil uma explicação para quem está começando ou aprendeu isso de forma errada.

Comment: https://translate.google.com/translate?hl=&sl=fr&tl=pt&u=http%3A%2F%2Fsasfepu78.ddns.net%2Farticles%2FCours_asm_68000_Feroce%20Lapin.pdf
Traduçao automatica de um Curso de ASM68 que eu escrivei 30 anos atrais; Com a ajuda de um pouco de café, e patienca isso vai permiir vc entender como funciona tudo isso. :)

Answer (score 245, accepted):

Uma *stack* (ou pilha), neste contexto, é uma forma otimizada para organizar dados na memória alocados em sequência e abandonados (sim, normalmente não há desalocação) em sequência invertida a da entrada.

[image: Pilha/Stack]

Um *heap*  (ou monte — ok, ninguém traduz isso) é a organização de memória mais flexível que permite o uso de qualquer área lógica disponível.

[image: Monte?Heap]

## De que pilha estamos falando?

Existem alguns conceitos de pilha muito difundidos em computação, para citar alguns:

- Existe a **pilha de execução** de alguma arquitetura onde as instruções e dados vão sendo empilhados e após executar algo ali, ocorre o desempilhamento.
- Existe a **pilha de chamadas de funções**, que se confunde com o gerenciamento de memória, onde as funções vão sendo chamadas e empilhadas e quando sua execução termina, ela sai da pilha.
- Existe a [**estrutura de dados genérica**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/15063/101) que empilha dados diversos. [Exemplo em C#](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/15063/101).

## Conceito abstrato

Os dois conceitos da pergunta são abstratos. Não existe fisicamente uma área da memória específica para a *stack* (e muito menos sua área é fisicamente empilhada) e não existe uma área reservada para o *heap*, pelo contrário, ele costuma ser bastante fragmentado. Usamos o conceito para entender melhor o funcionamento e suas implicações, principalmente no caso da pilha.

A maioria das arquiteturas de computadores modernos e populares não têm grandes facilidades para manipular essa *stack* de memória (costuma ter só o registrador de ponteiro de pilha). Assim como o *heap*, apesar que neste caso, instruções que ajudam manipular memória virtual, de uma certa forma ajudam a organizar o *heap*, mas isso vale pra toda memória, não só o *heap*.

## Ficando um pouco mais concreto

Já os sistemas operacionais estão bem cientes destes conceitos, e é fundamental que eles possuam alguma forma — mesmo que limitada — para manipular a memória das aplicações, principalmente nos sistemas modernos e de utilidade geral. Os sistemas modernos possuem um gerenciamento complexo, através do que se convencionou chamar de memória virtual, um conceito também abstrato, muitas vezes mal compreendido.

## Onde mexemos diretamente

Em Assembly ou C é muito comum ter contato com esse gerenciamento de memória. Em Assembly é comum manipular a *stack* quase diretamente, e em ambas linguagens, pelo menos a alocação e desalocação do *heap* devem ser feitas manualmente através da API do sistema operacional. Em C a *stack* é gerenciado pelo compilador, salvo alguma operação incomum que seja necessária.

Nada impede que se use alguma biblioteca que abstraia essa manipulação, mas isso só é comum em linguagens de mais alto nível. De fato, é muito comum que outras linguagens usem internamente a API do *OS* para fazer o gerenciamento pesado da memória, mas o acesso da memória no "varejo" é feito por um gerenciador próprio, em geral chamado de *garbage collector* (*GC*), através de técnicas de contagem de referências para um objeto no *heap* (há quem considere que isto não é uma técnica de *garbage collector*) ou de verificação posterior da existência de referências para o objeto no *heap*. Mesmo usando uma biblioteca mais abstrata, os conceitos permanecem.

Quanto mais alto nível, menos se precisa gerenciar tudo isso, mas entender o funcionamento geral é importante em todas linguagens.

Linguagens que não precisam de performance podem deixar tudo no *heap* para "facilitar" a compressão e acesso.

## Pilha

#### Alocação

Em condições normais, **a *stack* é alocada no início da execução da aplicação**, mais precisamente no início da *thread*, mesmo que a aplicação só tenha a *thread* principal.

A *stack* é uma porção contígua de memória reservada para empilhar os dados necessários durante a execução de blocos de código.

Cada necessidade de alocação é um trecho da *stack* que vai sendo usado sempre em sequência determinado por um marcador, ou seja, um apontador, um **ponteiro**, se "movimenta" para indicar que uma nova parte na sequência desta porção reservada está comprometida.

Quando algo reservado para um segmento não é mais necessário, este marcador se movimenta em direção contrária a sequência de dados indicando que alguns desses dados podem ser descartados (sobrepostos com novos dados).

A alocação de cada trecho da memória não existe na *stack*, é apenas o movimento deste ponteiro indicando que aquela área será usada por algum dado.

Grosso modo, podemos dizer que a aplicação tem total controle sobre a *stack*, exceto quando acaba o espaço disponível para ela.

Existem recursos para alterar manualmente o tamanho da *stack*, mas isso é incomum.

## Funcionamento

A pilha funciona usado uma forma LIFO (Last in, First Out) ou UEPS (Último a entrar, primeiro a sair).

O escopo de uma variável costuma definir o tempo de alocação na *stack*. Os dados usados como parâmetros e retorno de funções são alocados na *stack*. Por isso a pilha de chamadas de função se confunde com a pilha da memória.

Podemos dizer que os parâmetros são as primeiras variáveis de uma função alocadas na *stack*. O acesso aos dados na *stack* costuma ser feito de forma direta, mas há [indireções](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181032/101) também.

[image: alocação stack]

Deu para entender que cada *thread* tem sua própria *stack*, certo? E o tamanho da *stack* de cada *thread* criada pode ser definido antes da criação. Um valor *default* costuma ser usado.

A *stack* é considerada uma forma **automática** de alocação (muitas vezes confundida com **estática** — alocação que ocorre junto à execução —, logo na sua carga). Tecnicamente, existe outra área da memória que realmente é estática, que é alocada antes do início da execução. A área efetivamente estática não pode ser manipulada, não pode ser escrita (pelo menos não deveria poder). A *stack* em si é estática, apesar dos seus dados não serem, afinal, eles vão sendo colocados e abandonados conforme o seu uso, o seu gerenciamento é automático.

## Decisão sobre onde alocar

Assim como no *heap*, não é possível alocar dados na *stack* antes de saber seu tamanho (não precisa saber na hora de compilar, mas sim na hora de executar a alocação, mas na *stack* tem algumas restrições). Mas se o tamanho for indeterminado em tempo de compilação ou pode ser determinado como **possivelmente** grande (talvez poucas dezenas de *bytes*), provavelmente a alocação deva ocorrer no *heap*.

Linguagens de alto nível predeterminam isto. Outras deixam o programador ter mais controle, podendo até mesmo abusar da *stack* se for útil e o programador souber o que está fazendo.

#### Stack overflow

O famoso *stack overflow* ocorre quando você tenta alocar algo na *stack* e não há espaço reservado disponível. Também pode, em alguns casos se a linguagem prover mecanismos que permitam, haver *overflow* de um dado em cima de outro que venha a seguir na pilha. Execuções recursivas descontroladas causam *stack overflow*.

#### Outra pilha

Também existe uma pilha de chamadas que é aonde são armazenados os endereços para onde o ponteiro da pilha deve retornar quando termina a execução de uma função.

## Heap

#### Alocação

O *heap*, ao contrário da *stack*, não impõe um modelo, um padrão de alocação de memória. Isso não é muito eficiente mas é bastante flexível.

O *heap* é considerado **dinâmico**. Em geral você aloca ou desaloca pequenos trechos de memória, só para a necessidade do dado. Esta alocação pode ocorrer fisicamente em qualquer parte livre da memória disponível para seu processo.

O gerenciamento de memória virtual do sistema operacional, auxiliado por instruções do processador, ajudam a organizar isto.

De certa forma podemos dizer que a *stack* como um todo é o primeiro objeto alocado no *heap*.

Efetivamente, estas alocações reais costumam ocorrer em blocos de tamanho fixo chamados de páginas. Isso evita a aplicação fazer dezenas ou centenas de pequenas alocações que fragmentariam a memória de forma extrema, e evita chamadas ao sistema operacional, que troca contexto e costuma ser bem mais lento. Em geral todo sistema de alocação da memória aloca mais do que precisa e vai dando acesso à aplicação conforme ela precisa, em alguns casos, ele quase simula uma *stack*, por algum tempo, ou faz reorganização da memória (através de um *GC* compactador).

#### Desalocação

A desalocação do *heap* costuma acontecer:

- manualmente (correndo o risco de *bugs*), embora isto não esteja disponível para algumas linguagens;
- através do tal [*garbage collector*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/255769/101) que identifica quando uma parte do *heap* não é mais necessária;
- quando uma aplicação se encerra.

#### Depende de implementação

Até existem linguagens que possuem *heaps* especializados que podem ter um comportamento um pouco diferente, mas vamos simplificar para os casos comuns.

## Conceito abstrato

Fica claro que o *heap* não é uma área da memória, mesmo conceituando abstratamente, ele é um conjunto de pequenas áreas da memória. Fisicamente ele costuma ser fragmentado por toda a memória. Essas partes são muito flexíveis em tamanho e [tempo de vida](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/135572/101).

Por razões de segurança, é bom saber que desalocar é um conceito abstrato também. Costuma ser possível acessar dados de uma aplicação mesmo depois que ela tenha terminado. O conteúdo só é apagado por pedido manual ou quando uma área disponível é escrita novamente.

#### Custo do *heap*

A **alocação no *heap* "custa" caro**. Muitas tarefas devem ser realizados pelo sistema operacional para garantir a perfeita alocação de uma área para um trecho dele, principalmente em ambientes concorrentes (muito comuns hoje em dia), e mesmo quando não precisa do SO, ainda tem um algoritmo complexo para alocar. Desalocar ou disponibilizar de volta uma área também tem seu custo, em alguns casos para a alocação custar mais barato a liberação custa bem caro (ironicamente pode ser controlada por várias pilhas).

Até existem formas de evitar as chamadas ao sistema operacional para cada alocação necessária, mas ainda assim o "custo" de processamento disto é considerado alto. Manter listas (em alguns casos ligadas) de áreas ou páginas alocadas não é algo trivial para o processador, pelo menos comparando com o movimento do ponteiro que é necessário na *stack*.

#### Funcionamento

[image: alocação heap]

O *heap* é acessado através de ponteiros. Mesmo em linguagens que não exista o conceito de ponteiros disponível para o programador, isto é realizado internamente de forma transparente.

[image: exemplo de alocação geral]

Note que no exemplo, um objeto do tipo `class1` é alocado no *heap*. Mas há uma referência para este objeto, que é alocada na *stack* (em alguns casos poderia não estar).

Esta alocação é necessária porque o tamanho do objeto pode ser muito grande para caber na *stack* (ou pelo menos ocupar uma parte considerável), ou porque ele pode sobreviver por mais tempo do que a função que criou ele.

Se estivesse na *stack* a "única" forma de mantê-lo "vivo" seria copiando para a função chamadora, e assim sucessivamente para todas as outras, onde ele seja necessário. Imagine como isso sai "caro". Da forma como é organizado, só a referência, que é curta, é que precisa ser copiada, e isto pode ser feito só usando registradores, super rápido.

## Conclusão

Então o *runtime* de uma linguagem de programação se comunica com o OS para gerenciar a memória. Se esse *runtime* é exposto para o programador depende do objetivo da linguagem. Em linguagens chamadas "gerenciadas", tudo isso ocorre, os dois conceitos existem e precisam ser entendidos, mas você não tem que manipular manualmente o *heap*. Ele passa ser tão transparente quanto a *stack* é em outras linguagens mais baixo nível (exceto Assembly).

A alocação de ambos costuma ser realizada na RAM, mas nada impede que seja em outro local. A memória virtual pode colocar todo ou parte da *stack* ou do *heap* em memória de massa, por exemplo.

"Roubei" algumas imagens [desta resposta do SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/79923/221800) que são muito boas para ilustrar tudo isso.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: "Em Assembly é comum manipular o stack quase diretamente" porque "quase"? 
move.w d1,-(sp)
bsr my_function
addq.l #2,sp
Vc édita direitamente o "stack pointer". Não tem outro jeito.

Answer (score 80):

A tradução de "stack" é pilha, isto é, uma estrutura de dados em que o último elemento a entrar é o primeiro a sair (pense numa pilha de livros). A pilha, portanto, funciona de forma bastante simples - elementos são adicionados/removidos de forma organizada/restrita, o que permite que os processadores sejam otimizados para realizar as operações envolvidas (e.g. operadores intel possuem registradores dedicados para guardar o endereço da base e do topo da pilha). Por isso, se pode dizer que a pilha é mais rápida que a heap.

Um conceito relacionado à pilha é o de "call frame". Quando funções são chamadas, ponteiros e parâmetros são gravados no topo da pilha de modo que a função chamada tenha acesso aos parametros para executar e depois o programa possa continuar executando do ponto onde houve a chamada de função. Novamente, o processador pode oferecer suporte para isso (comando call do assembly para 8086, por exemplo).

Eu não lembro de ter visto tradução para o termo "heap", mas a principal característica da porção de memória dedicada a um programa a que se refere como "heap" é que ela é destinada à alocação dinâmica de memória (famosos alloc()/malloc()/realloc() em C/new em C++ por exemplo). É justamente pelo fato de que os elementos alocados na heap podem ser alocados/desalocados a qualquer momento e em qualquer ordem que o acesso à heap tende a ser mais lento, podendo levar à fragmentação de memória (espaços perdidos entre regiões de memória utilizada).

Como já mencionei, os processadores intel oferecem suporte para controle da pilha diretamente. Para outros processadores, o sistema operacional pode precisar cuidar disso. Em qualquer caso, quando o programa/thread é inicializado, cabe ao sistema operacional reservar uma porção de memória para o programa/thread. Em muitos casos essa área é "compartilhada" entre a pilha e a heap, uma delas começa dos menor endereço e a outra começa do maior endereço e as duas crescem uma em direção à outra. Quando uma encontra à outra, ocorre uma OutOfMeMory exception ou algo do gênero.

Em assembly/C, o programador deve estar ciente dessas diferenças e estará diretamente envolvido na escolha de onde alocar cada variável. Em linguagems mais "modernas", como Java, que tem conveniências como garbage collection, os conceitos ainda se aplicam, mas é mais fácil um programador viver sem saber os detalhes do que acontece embaixo do capô.

Comment: +1, boa resposta. Falta so' indicar que e' reservada uma stack para cada uma das threads, enquanto que a heap e' partilhada por todas as threads dentro do mesmo processo.

Answer (score 47):

Gostaria de apresentar aqui meu entendimento menos técnico do que as repostas dadas acima mas que podem ser de ajuda ao programador que quer apenas saber do que se trata sem se aprofundar no assunto.

A memória Stack é utilizada para armazenar argumentos de uma função, procedure, método. Sendo ela estática pré-alocada no start do programa e desalocada no final, e por isso é mais veloz do que a memória Heap que precisa ser alocada/desalocada a cada momento que for necessário.

A alocação da memória stack normalmente é feita uma única alocação de um grande bloco e para cada argumento de função/método/procedure é destinada uma parte ou pedaço dessa memória. O Fato de a memória stack ter tamanho fixo especificado no projeto, faz dela potencial fonte de problemas se no caso for especificado tamanho menor do que se pretende usar no programa.

Por isso era comum ver no passado (menos hoje em dia) as famosas mensagems de erro que dá título a este site **"Stack Overflow"**, significando que a memória stack acabou. Isso ocorre ou ocorria muito nas chamadas de funções em cascata (função que chama outra, que chama outra, que...)  e também quando há chamadas recursivas de uma mesma função/procedure/método em que não há o controle de término ou que o término da mesma usaria tanta memória stack que seria necessário aumentar seu tamanho e recompilar o programa.

Hoje em dia é raro ocorrer o famoso **"stack overflow"** devido aos compiladores de hoje reservarem como default uma quantidade bem grande de stack em seu projeto, o que não ocorria no passado em que computadores possuiam bem menos memória do que os atuais, não sendo possível alocar muita quantidade de stack naqueles tempos remotos.

A memória Heap é muito usada para alocação de objetos e desalocados no final do seu uso.  A memória num conceito genérico pode ser estática ou dinâmica, a estática (também chamada de Global) usa o Data Segment(processadores intel 80x86), já a dinâmica usa o Heap e é isso que diferencia uma da outra.

Mas qual a diferença do Heap para a Stack ? Enquanto a stack é usada por funções/métodos/procedures, a heap pode ser usada em qualquer ponto do programa normalmente em criação de objetos ou ponteiros para alguma estrutura de dados.

Comment: Não deixa de ser uma explicação, ela não está errada, mas dá indicações "enganosas" de como é funcionamento destes conceitos.

Comment: Entendo, mas como disse no início, não pretendi me aprofundar muito tecnicamente, já que existia outras respostas acima mais completas na parte técnica. Procurei focar mais na utilização e como que funciona no processador 80x88.

Comment: Tem lingagem usando registro do processor para parametros e outros linguagem usando o "stack". Stack e Haep sao pedaço de memorio. Em linguagem tipo Pascal, C etc... vc tem limitaçães. Em ASM vc nao tem e vc pode usar a memoria do jeito que vc quer.

Answer (score 42):

### Definições

#### Pilha

Na pilha, são guardados objetos alocados dentro de escopos de funções incluindo variáveis locais das funções, argumentos, endereços das áreas de código sendo executadas antes de outras chamadas de função, retorno de funções.

A alocação de memória ocorre de forma sequencial e, como a posição desses objetos é conhecida durante o tempo de compilação, nós podemos atribuir nomes próprios a esses objetos e acessá-los diretamente. Quando um objeto que é alocado no *stack* sai de seu respectivo escopo, o objeto é automaticamente deletado. Então você não precisa se preocupar com alocação e desalocação de memória com objetos da pilha mas atenção, o *stack* tem um tamanho limitado.

#### Heap

O *heap* é o local de memória adequado para alocar muitos objetos grandes, pois esta seção do programa é bem maior que a pilha, e seu tamanho é limitado apenas pela memória virtual disponível na sua máquina. Os objetos alocados no *heap* são todos aqueles alocados usando new ou `malloc()` (objetos alocados dinamicamente). Como a posição em que esses objetos vão estar durante a execução do programa é desconhecida em tempo de compilação, a única forma de acessá-los é via Pointeros. Deve lembrar-se de controlar a desalocação desses objetos, pois não são destruídos automaticamente.

### Repostas

> Algum deles é mais rápido que o outro? Se um é claramente mais rápido, por que existe o outro?

A `Pilha` (Stack) é mais rápida pois as variáveis/objetos são criados em tempo de compilação, a pilha não se estende pela memoria virtual da máquina (HD) logo em algum momento um objeto/variável alocado no `Heap` podem estar armazenado no HD e logo este deverá ser carregado na RAM.

> Faz diferença se estou usando, por exemplo, Assembly, C, Java, ou Javascript, Windows ou Linux? Isso é controlado pela "linguagem" ou pelo sistema operacional?

Linguagens como Java e Python possuem um Garbage Collector que remove da memoria objetos e variáveis que já não estão mais sendo referenciados. Quanto a diferença entre SOs pode haver uma quanto ao endereçamento, esta questão acho que pode ser melhor explicada com este *link* para o [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22446991/stack-and-heap-address-region-is-differs-in-windows-and-linux)

Referência: http://www.unidev.com.br/index.php?/topic/55299-entendendo-as-divis%C3%B5es-de-mem%C3%B3ria-stack-heap-global-e-code/

Comment: Só um detalhe, a posição de nenhum objeto é conhecido em tempo de compilação.